# How to suppress browser backdoor for form validation by changing element attribute

Tags: html, validation

I made some HTML form and added some kind of validation to check are all form fields filled up or some of them is empty. In order to disable user to submit unfinished form I wrote in validation code that submit button is disabled, and it worked fine until I decided to play with browser: I loaded page, then press F12 and in window bellow I made click on Elements tab. Here I found disabled submit button, with this text:

```
<input name="btnsub" type="submit" id="btnsubmit" value="Sign me" disabled>
```

Then I put mouse pointer over the word "disabled" and clicked with right mouse key. In contest menu I choose Edit attribute and now selected word "disabled". I corrected it as "enabled". Voila, submit button was in working state, enabled, I clicked on it and I signed even not all form's data weren't presented. Is there some kind of trick to suppress this "browser feature", to disallow evil user to jump over this "protection"? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that there is. However, it is already expected that you'll have your more robust "protection" or validation in your server side codes, and that's what you'll need the most against advanced users; those who do hacks/tricks with developer tools as what youre doing..

Comment: Hi TyrHunter... In meantime I tried with visibility attribute too, but it also show up in developer window of browser. It's enough to edit attribute (delete) and again same song, same problem. Maybe to add some kind of session variable for check on calling page!? If this variable isn't empty then pass, if not then go back? all with PHP...

Comment: Hello @LudusH, what was this for? "Maybe to add some kind of session variable for check on calling page!? If this variable isn't empty then pass, if not then go back? all with PHP" please be specific on what you would really want.

Comment: The purpose of this form isn't like some kind of login form, with connection to database but just to check is user entered all necessary data before data are processing. If some of them isn't present then calculation would fail. Due that I wrote JS code that disable/enable submit button based on fact are there all minimal data. This omission of browser forced me to think for better solution how to stop user with unfilled form in progress to next page. If I decide to put in use some session variable then problem is how to make some PHP-session variable from JS-code.

Comment: @Ludus H You can get values of php variables in a js file like this: <script type="text/javascript">
document.ready(function() {
<?php echo $script; ?>
});
</script> so maybe you can make some PHP-session variable from a js file too?